# HTML field to be set as optional

Tags: html, css

I have a quick question which I am a bit confused about...

I know in HTML you can have fields required in a form but I want to make the full name field below required which is fine

```
<input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" placeholder="Full
Name" required="required"/><br/>
```

But the tiny issue I am having which I dont know how to fix is I want to make the other field optional so the user can submit the form even without filing it out.

```
<input type="text" name="Other" id="fullname"
placeholder="Other"/><br/>
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks ! :)

Comment: if i understood your question correctly, you will just have to remove the `required` attribute from the field you don't want to be required and be good.

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 3):

Fields are optional by default. Don't put the "required" flag if you don't want it to be required...!

Comment: I removed the required and when I fill in the formand enter all the fields data except the other field and press submit it says error cannot submit but when i fill everything out then it submits ?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `required` attribute from the one you want to be optional and it won't require that to be filled out for submission.